# Adobe Illustrator files (*.ai) scripting?

Tags: scripting, adobe-illustrator

I'd like to export layer structures(and layer itself to file) to folders using a scripting language(preferably which will run on mac and windows)

I found a ready to use sample for Photoshop (*.psd) files.
http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html

Wonder if same thing can be done to *.ai files.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Photoshop Illustrator supports scripts written in AppleScript, JavaScript or VBScript. You can find more info at the [Adove Developer Connection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html) site dealing with Illustrator scripting.